# What effect does diluting a buffer have on its buffer capacity?

Tags: acid-base, ph

What effect does diluting a buffer have on its buffer capacity? I am not worried about the effect on the pH, just the buffer capacity.

Answer (score 2):

The buffer capacity β is a direct function of the concentrations of all protolytes in the solution. Thus, if the concentration of the protolytes decreases you should then expect a decrease in the buffer capacity.